# Quilkblox not returning chat history

Tags: ios, chat, quickblox

We are facing an issue in Quilkbox APi. We are creating a chat application in which We are setting up rooms. Chat messages are sending well. but the issues is we are not able to retrieve chat history.

in Rooms when a user sends the message to other user which is offline then message is sending well but when user stop running app and then again run the app then the old messages are not received.

When both users are online and chatting with each other then chat is working fine all messages are showing. but when when they stop app and then again run the app then the old messages are not showing

we have checked that the method of the delegate QBchatDelegate

- (void)chatRoomDidReceiveMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message fromRoom:(NSString *)roomName

is not being called first time when user opens the app but when user send the message in room then this method is called and the message will show.

What will be the issue of not returning the chat history

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you create temporary chat rooms (not persistent).

Temporary room - A room that is destroyed if the last occupant exits

Try to create persistent room

Use this guide http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_room